# Почему такой процент захода на сайт уходит после 2 секунду?

Tags: seo

Есть интернет магазин. Грузится шустро, в районе 1-2 секунд но процент ухода с сайт в первые 2 секунды 40% по данным метрики. Это нормальная практика?

Comment: При чем тут метка seo?

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть сигнал несоответствия информации вашего веб-сайта в результатах поиска и содержания веб-страниц. Пользователи видят какую-то интересующую их информацию и переходят на ваши веб-страницы. Однако там сразу же видят, что это их не интересует, и уходят.

Альтернатива. Веб-страницы куда переходят пользователи имеют непонятную структуру или непонятную навигацию и это отгоняет пользователей от ваших веб-страниц.

Answer (score 1):

А вот не надо было покупать рекламу, где делается принудительный переход на твой сайт вместо ожидаемого пользователем действия. Пары секунд как раз хватит, чтобы понять, в каком из окон (старом или новом) открылся полезный контент и закрыть другое.